# Elevar fração à potência

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu preciso elevar um número a um determinado `expoente`, mas não sei como fazer no caso de `frações`. Por exemplo, eu sei que para elevar `2` a `terceira potência`, eu devo fazer `2**3`. Porém, se eu quiser elevar `1/2` à terceira potencia, como ficaria?

Meu código se encontra logo abaixo.

Do jeito que estou fazendo, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1/2'`

Eu gostaria que o usuário digitasse um número na forma de fração `(1/2)` e não na forma decimal `0.5`.

```
base = float(input('Digite a base: '))
exp = int(input('Digite o expoente: '))

result = base**exp

print('a base ', base, ' elevada ao expoente ', exp, ' é igual a: ', result)
```

Comment: Roger, qual a sua intenção com essa edição adicionando um novo código na pergunta?

Comment: Eu pretendo tratar todos os casos de uma base elevada a um expoente, fracionário ou não. Por exemplo, 2^2, ou 2^(3/2). A execução do código alterado dar esse erro: File "main.py", line 8
    if (base_array.find('/')==-1):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

KeyboardInterrupt


Comment: E já viu a minha resposta? Já não faz tudo que precisa?

Comment: Eu estava tentando aqui, mas quando digitei o expoente fracionário deu o seguinte erro. Daí, estou tentando outra solução. Olha, o erro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    exp = int(input('Expoente: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3/7'

Comment: Sim, porque não havia nada especificando que o expoente poderia ser uma fração também; bastaria você ler, entender o código e adaptá-lo.

Comment: Roger, viu que fiz edições na minha resposta? Restou alguma dúvida?

Comment: Olá, está funcionando como eu quero agora. Só não compreendi por que você fez map(int, base.split('/', 1)) e depois atribui "1" ao denominator.

Comment: O `map` é para converter a entrada para inteiro. Se digitar `'1/2'` ele retorna `(1, 2)` como inteiros. O denominador igual a 1 é quando não é digitado uma fração na entrada, por exemplo `'4'`.

Comment: Entendi. Grato.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html) para lidar com frações:

```
from fractions import Fraction

base = Fraction(1, 2)
exponent = 3

result = base**exponent

print(result)  # 1/8
```

Se a ideia é aceitar como entrada do usuário valores no formato numerador/denominador, você precisará tratar a fim de gerar a sua fração final.

```
base = input('Base: ')
exponent = input('Expoente: ')

if '/' in base:
    numerator, denominator = map(int, base.split('/', 1))
else:
    numerator = int(base)
    denominator = 1

base = Fraction(numerator, denominator)

if '/' in exponent:
    numerator, denominator = map(int, exponent.split('/', 1))
else:
    numerator = int(exponent)
    denominator = 1

exponent = Fraction(numerator, denominator)

print(base**exponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma ótima solução:

```
base = input('Digite a base: ')
exp = int(input('Digite o expoente: '))

m_array = base.split("/")
base = int(m_array[0])/int(m_array[1])

result = base**exp

print('a base ', m_array[0] + "/" + m_array[1], 'elevada ao expoente ', exp, ' é igual a: ', result)
```

Comment: Funcionou. Só que eu quero que o resultado venha também na forma de fração com numerado e denominador. Ou seja, em result, eu devo ter 1/2 e não 0.5. Grato.

Comment: @rogerroger pronto

Comment: Tá dando ess erro:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1_potencias.py", line 12, in <module>
    exp = int(input('Digite o expoente: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1/2'

Comment: @rogerroger, esse erro acontece quando você não digita a base e pressiona o enter. Para resolver esse problema você terá que verificar se os dados foram digitados e se foram digitados corretamente.

Comment: Tem razão. Como pretendo que o programa também interprete denominador "1", ou seja, 4/1, por exemplo, vou tentar tratar esse caso com um if. Grato.